# $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} E [\sqrt{a+X} ]$, $X > 0$ a.s., $a \geq 0$

Tags: probability

Although maybe this could have been posted at cross-validated, I actually have a financial application in mind.

**Problem:**

There is a very elementary mistake somewhere, but I can't see it:

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X > 0$ almost surely. Let $a$ be a non-negative real-number. Denote by $p(x)$ the probability density of $X$. Then,
$$
E [\sqrt{a + X} \;] = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{a+x}\; p(x) dx
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} E [\sqrt{a+X}\; ] = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x}}\; p(x) dx > 0
$$

On the other hand, we can also consider the probability density $q(\sqrt{a+x})$ of the random variable $\sqrt{a+X}$ directly, and since $\sqrt{a+X} > \sqrt{a}$ almost surely,
$$
E [\sqrt{a + X} \;] = \int_\sqrt{a}^\infty \sqrt{a+x}\; q(\sqrt{a+x}) d\sqrt{a+x}
$$
Now,
$$
d\sqrt{a+x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a+x}}
$$
and hence
$$
E [\sqrt{a + X} \;] = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty q(\sqrt{a+x}) dx
$$
Differentiate the above expressiont wrt to $a$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} E [\sqrt{a + X} \;] &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+x}} \frac{\partial q(\sqrt{a+x})}{\partial \sqrt{a+x}} dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_\sqrt{a}^\infty \frac{\partial q(\sqrt{a+x})}{\partial \sqrt{a+x}} d\sqrt{a+x} \\
&= - \frac{1}{2} q(\sqrt{a})
\end{align}

Since 1. the sign is wrong, and 2. $q(\sqrt{a}) = 0$, this is (twice) in contradiction with what was derived earlier, namely,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} E [\sqrt{a+X}\; ] = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x}}\; p(x) dx > 0
$$

So where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This clearly belongs on stats.SE. The end application does not matter when the question is this technical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your $q$ is (it doesn't seem well defined). For clarity, let
$$ Y = \sqrt{a+X} > \sqrt a \; \; a.s. $$

For cdf's we have:
$$ F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(\sqrt{a+X}\leq y) = P(X\leq y^2-a)=F_X(y^2-a) $$

By taking derivatives, we get the following relationship between pdf's:

$$ p_Y(y) = 2y p_X(y^2-a) $$

So:

$$E[Y] = \int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty  y p_Y(y) dy =\int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty  2y^2 p_X(y^2-a) dy  $$
$$= \int_{{0}}^\infty  \sqrt{a+x}p_X(x) dx = E[\sqrt{a+X}]$$

(after a variable transformation $x=y^2-a$ in the third equality).

We then may want to take the derivative wrt to $a$ of:
$$E[Y] = \int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty  y p_Y(y) dy = \int_{{0}}^\infty 2^{-1}p_Y(\sqrt{z+a}) dz $$

(after transformation $y=\sqrt{z+a}$), which brings us back to square 1 (given the pdf relationships).

Comment: Agree with your expressions, see also my last comment below. Giving you both +10, thanks.

Comment: One more variable change shows we get back to square 1. I added a note.

Answer (score 2):

Your last claim $\frac{1}{2} \int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty \frac{\partial q(\sqrt{a+x})}{\partial \sqrt{a + x}} d \sqrt{a+x} = -\frac{1}{2}q(\sqrt{a})$ is not true.

---

Realized that the part above is irrelevant. Assuming $q$ is nice enough, the problems lies in the part of taking derivative $\frac{\partial q(\sqrt{a+x})}{\partial a}$. The mistake is that $q_a(y) = q(a, y)$ itself is also a function of $a$. So when taking derivative, we need take care of both arguments.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Firstly, fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply to improper integral. Secondly $q$ itself may not even be continuous let alone differentiable.

Comment: btw, even if you assume $q$ is very nice, you would have a $q(\infty)$ on the right hand side

Comment: FTC can be extended to improper integrals. I will think more about your point regarding differentiability, but I am not sure (yet) this is the answer. EDIT: well q will go to zero as x goes to infinity.

Comment: the claim q goes to zero as x goes to infinity is not true, the limit may not even exist

Comment: Yes, I think you are right that $q = q(a,y(a))$ which if not taken into account leads to garbage out. And/or, using @ir7 notation, $Y(a)$ is a different random variable for each value of the parameter $a$, hence I don't know if $dE[Y(a)]/da$ is even well-defined.

Comment: Though not very relevant to the question, I later realized that even the claim $q(\sqrt{a}) = 0$ is not true. More precisely, let $q$ be a pdf of a random variable $Y$ with values in $[a,b]$. Assuming $q$ is differentiable, if one would like to apply FTC

Comment: $\int_a^b q'(y)dy = q(b) - q(a)$, one needs to make sure $q$ is continuous at $a$. Though changing the value of $q(a)$ to $0$ will still make it a pdf of the random variable, it in generaly may not satisfy the continuity requirement.